# Error in jquery.js file in chrome extension project

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have this strange error.

I am developing a chrome extension using 'chrome dev editor'. The project is using jQuery. It was working fine but after I open the jquery.js file it shows errors like

> missing semicolon 
>   missing () invoking a constructor

The project cannot be loaded because of this.

I have not done any modification in the jquery.js file. It was dowloaded from 'http://jquery.com/download/'.

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "TextExtn",
  "short_name": "TextExtn",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
   "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [ "scripts/jquery-1.12.0.js","scripts/welcome.js"
        ]
    }
]

}
```

Comment: Can you provide your manifest file, so we can guess what else is going on?

Comment: I have updated it here.

Comment: You should try jQuery 2.2 instead of 1.x branch; also, use the minified version.